# Protractor index in loop stays the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, protractor

I have a problem with the following piece of code.

```
var elements = element.all(by.repeater('repeater'));            
        elements.then(function(array){  
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){             
                var openText = elements.get(i);             
                openText.getText().then(function(txt){                  
                    if (txt.indexOf(eventName) >= 0){                       
                        openText.element(by.buttonText('Close')).click();   
                    };
                });         
            };  
        });
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following:
 - I need to go through all the elements in elements.all that's why I'm using elements.then(array). I need to find specific string in those elements, that's why indexOf. In that element I need to find spefific buttonText which should be on index "i" and I could call it using get(i). But it turns out that I always get the las index in the array. Is there a way to solve this? I basically need to click on an element that is inside another element. I can find one element by text and another by buttonText inside that first element.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your HTML-code, this will greatly help us help you.

Comment: Also, have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29372555/ui-protractor-find-click-select-box-based-on-text-search/29373836#29373836). I believe the solution should help you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found part of solution on the link provided. The rest I figured out.